# How do I read Windows unicode files via php and store them in a utf-8 database?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, unicode, registry

The Windows Registry editor created Windows Unicode (UTF-16-le) files when you export a registry key.  I am trying to figure out the best way to import those files into a mysql database using PHP so that they can later be downloaded as a unicode file again?

When I import them into the database I am using `file_get_contents()` and just storing them into the utf-8 column.  When I export them, I first use `mb_convert_encoding($row['reg'], 'UTF-16')` and issue headers to have the file downloaded.  When I open them in Windows, though, the content is just garbled.

Any thoughts on the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Are you doing a `mb_convert_encoding()` when you insert the data?

Comment: Have you checked where the corruption occurs? Is your database connection UTF? Is the table UTF? etc...

Comment: Yes, everything is UTF across the board.  Names, connection, table etc.

I was not though mb_convert_encoding it on the input.  What would be the process there?  Use file_get_contents to read the file into a string and the use $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought I would share the solution that I was able to figure out. The trick was to use UTF-16LE as the original charset.

```
mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents($file), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE');
```